# Routing devise confirmation email to page where new user registered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, registration

I have customized the registration process with devise to happen all within a modal. It works similarly to a paywall, where you visit a path that needs registration and are prompted to register at that moment in a modal.

When the confirmation email is sent it routes the new user to the homepage but I would like to route them the path where they originally signed up on.

So if they signed up at `www.example.com/sample_path` when they confirm they should be routed there rather then `www.example.com`

I know that this line is what creates the registration link but I am not sure how to customize the path at this point

```
<%= link_to 'Next, confirm your account', confirmation_url(@resource, confirmation_token: @token) %>
```

Comment: You would have to record the path when the user first signs for example through a hidden input in the registrations form and then store it somewhere that persists across requests like for example a cookie, the session or in an additional column on your users table. After you have done those steps its simply a matter of overriding the `after_confirmation_path_for` method. https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/451ff6d49c71e543962d2b29d77f2e744b2d47e1/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb#L28

Comment: See also https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FControllers%2FStoreLocation:stored_location_for

Comment: Thank you max. We did resolved this by recording the path in a session cookie and overriding the `after_confirmation_path_for` to redirect to the path that the user registered on.